# angularjs phoneformat edit page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am using PhoneFormat to format phone number in my angularjs application. In the pure display page, following line of code works well.

```
 <td>{{contact.PhoneNumber | tel}}</td>
```

But in the Edit or create new page, the following line of code **does not work**. Meaning , it does not format to (xxx)xxx-xxxx.. **It just simply shows up as 7145551212 kind of number.**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="PhoneNumber">Cell Phone Number</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9" >
        <input type="text"  data-ng-model="contact.PhoneNumber | tel"  id="PhoneNumber" name="PhoneNumber" class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
```

code for filter is as follows:

```
angular.module('appointmentReminderApp')
.filter('tel', function () {
    return function (phoneNumber) {
        if (!phoneNumber)
            return phoneNumber;

        return formatLocal('US', phoneNumber);
    }
});
```

Comment: can u post the code for `filter tel` ?

Comment: what is the `formatLocal()` function  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can format it inside the controller and assign that value to model

for ex:

```
$scope.PhoneNumber = $filter("tel")(7145551212);
```

and don't forget to inject `$filter` in to the controller as.

```
app.controller("testCtrl" , function($scope , $filter) {....
```

here is a simple demo [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/zh8nujt4/)